# Possible to create a Polling method to check for 'Popup' during the life of a Browser Instance?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Possible to create a Polling method to check for 'Popup' during the life of a Browser Instance?

For example if i have random popups appearing at anytime of a user journey is it possible to close the popup using a unique ID when appearing?

thanks for your help

```
@BeforeMethod
public void closeGiveawayPopup() throws Exception {
    try {
        List<WebElement> elements = getDriver().findElements(By.cssSelector(".close"));
        for (WebElement element : elements) {
            if (element.isDisplayed()) {
                element.click();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw (e);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `user journey` ? How it related to `selenium`?

Comment: @Andersson iam creating a webdriver framework, but popups++ appear randomly at any stage of the test for example signing into account, I have a method which closes the popup but need a way to continuously check during the execute of each test

Comment: What kind of pop-ups? Is it suitable for you to disable pop-ups at all? What kind of browser (`webdriver`) you use?

Comment: @Andersson im using both Chrome and firefox but its appears at different points when using the two different types of browsers, i have tried the following code with CHrome:     ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
     options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
     options.addArguments("chrome.switches","--disable-extensions");
     webdriver = new ChromeDriver(options); but dosnt work

Comment: You should update your question with code of all attempts you've tried already and exhaustive issue description to avoid downvoting

Comment: @Andersson i have discovered if i disable JS the popup disappears but i need to enable JS during tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your JUnit framework, possibly, to accomplish this using either @Before and/or @After (or correspondingly in TestNG @BeforeMethod and/or @AfterMethod)  Each step (JBehave) or test run could check before and/or after for an alert, and close it correspondingly.  This way, at least, there's only one method required in every module and not in every test.  I'm not certain of the exact syntax of the JUnit or TestNG, we use JUnit, but we don't use the annotations since we instead use the BDD provided with JBehave instead.  It does, however have similar @Before and @After varieties.

Comment: thank you so much for you help, that what exactly what I was thinking, the problem is when I add the 'New method listed above' inside BeforeMethod which is housed inside my BrowserFactory the scripts dont seem to load at all; not even point to the required URL

Comment: Which testing framework are you using?  I don't think inside the browserfactory would be the appropriate place.  In my case (JBehave) I would place the actual code to check for and handle the pop-ups either in a general utilities module or inside the steps files themselves.  It can certainly be in the same module as your browser factory, but it needs to be a separate method which would then be called in the @Before section of the steps module.

Comment: thanks again for you help, please see the latest version of my framework so far (Image attached above), please could you provide any thoughts or opinions from your experience? Any architectural changes would be much appreciated

Comment: I would create a new class file under the Utilities package called Popups or something along that line, and place your popup handling methods inside that class.  Then in your test file(s) I would declare a @Before and make a call to the appropriate check/close routines in your Popups class.

Comment: thanks again for your help, hope you have a great weekend

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `FirefoxProfile` as below:

```
FirefoxProfile customProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
customProfile.setPreference("dom.disable_beforeunload", true);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(customProfile);
```